# How can i know How many and which pages, files of my site are crawl-able by search engines?

Tags: search-engines

How can i know How many and which pages, files of my site are crawl-able by search engines?

Answer (score 1):

They are all crawlable if another page links to them. You can prevent certain web robots from indexing your pages with a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file, which they are supposed to respect, but even with one in place there are probably web robots which won't respect it. I know the big boys out there (Google, Yahoo, Bing...) **will** respect a robots.txt file, but there are probably smaller ones out there that may not.

Comment: is there any tool which can tell how search engine crawling my site ?

Comment: **If** or **how** ? You can check your web access logs, most robots have their own special user-agent string such as **Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)** (for Google).

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer here

http://www.seobench.com/search-engine-crawler-simulator/index.php